# How to perform multiple logistic regression for a continuous dependent variable with values bounded between 0 and 1?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I'd like to model the response of three species functional groups (proportion of total abundance) to different environmental gradients. I thought a multiple linear regression could work well, but now I heard that I should use multiple logistic regression, because my response variable (proportion of total counts) is bounded between 0 and 1. However, when I try to perform logistic regression in R with my data, I have the following error message:

```
In eval(family$initialize): non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

More specifically, here is my very simple code:

```
test_clusters <- read.table(clusters.txt)

head(test_clusters, 3)# checking data

    Cluster1   Cluster2  Cluster3  PC1_soil  PC2_soil precip  disturb
P2 0.8297214 0.01857585 0.1517028  2.200434 0.5114511    647 51.98126
P4 0.3196347 0.04109589 0.6392694 -1.016489 1.9255986    591 16.47774
P7 0.7352941 0.03361344 0.2310924  2.479751 0.6501704    516 20.30064

## test_clusters[,1:3] are the proportional abundance of each cluster, while [,4:7] are the predictor (environmental) variables

## Trying to perform multiple logistic regression to test the response of each cluster to the environmental gradients

model <- glm (Cluster1 ~ PC1_soil + PC2_soil + precip + disturb,
              data = test_clusters, family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

Then I have the error message commented above:

```
In eval(family$initialize): non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

Someone know what's the problem? Any other suggestion about the more appropriate test for this kind of data would valuable.

Comment: Your difficulty is that logistic regression requires a 0/1 response variable, not one that is in $[0,1]$.  I think beta regression is more what you'll need, perhaps the betareg package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/betareg.pdf

Comment: If you have the counts (not just the proportions) you could perhaps use the multinomial Poisson transformation, see https://www.math.ntnu.no/inla/r-inla.org/papers/multinomial-poisson.pdf.

Comment: You say your response variable is a "proportion of total counts", do you know the constituent counts (hits, & totals)?

Comment: yes, I know the constituent counts..

Comment: If you have the counts, then just do a binomial regression.  See the help for glm for how to specify the dependent variable.

Answer (score 1):

You get the warning (not error) because you did not use the `weight` argument to `glm` with the `binomial` family and a 1 dimensional outcome variable that is in the $(0,1)$ range.

Do you know the total population for each `Cluster1` fraction? If so, use this as the `weight` argument. Though, I may have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to try to use the weight function and then I will give you a feedback.

Comment: Actually, it did not works, and the same message occurs. I'm not sure if I have understood prety well. I used the total count for the population as the weight. So, if cluster 1 fraction is 0.5 for a community with 100 individuals, the total population (weight) is 50... Is that correct?

Comment: No then the weight should be `100`. The warnings comes when `m <- weights * y; any(abs(m - round(m)) > 0.001)`. I.e., a rough test for whether `weight` times the outcome is an integer.